# Translation of a "district health authority"

Tags: traducción

I have to translate a report into Spanish from Turkish. In Turkey, Istanbul, we have districts in cities, see here for [mine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9Ei%C5%9Fli). In this question, let's call the district's name as Şişli (so you can give a precise answer).

In the stamps of the report, I have several problems. I enumerate it so you can answer easily.

1) First of all, I know the "Ministry of Health of Turkey" translates as "Ministerio de Sanidad de Turquía". (Is it correct?)

2) What is the translation of "health authority of the Şişli district" in Spanish? Everything I've come up with can not be found in the Google so I suspect they are used. **Here "authority" means the following: It is not a hospital, or a medical centre of sort. It is the unit that organises and manages health related things in the district and consists of officials.**

3) I also need the translation of head of this unit. Head of health authority of the district? I've also come up with some ideas but I am not sure they correspond to something meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, **"Ministerio de Sanidad de Turquía"** is correct.

2) That depends on how a country is subdivided; in Spain we have "Comunidades Autónomas" and into them, "Provincias" (and finally "cities", obviously). A generic term to refer to the competent organism of health on all of those cases would be **"Delegación de Sanidad"**, which means the authority in charge of health on that area.

3) That would be translated, in the same way, as **"Delegado de Sanidad"** of each area.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What is the correct way to add the name of the district then? Delegación de Sanidad de Şişli?

Comment: Glad to be helpful. Exactly, but remember that's a generic form to refer to it; I have no idea whether in Şişli they have a specifically-defined-term call it.

Comment: they accepted this version. :) they said it is incorrect but we can understand what it is. :)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Maybe it was too generic and in Turkish may exist much more specific terms for it, but good news anyway :) That means the rest of your work was way good enough; Congrats! ;)

Comment: Yes, I was trying to avoid an official translator (so expensive), a few Spanish friends, and SE did the job :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> "Ministry of Health of Turkey" translates as "Ministerio de Sanidad de Turquía". (Is it correct?)

Seems like a pretty reasonable translation. There is a [*Ministerio de Sanidad*](http://www.msssi.gob.es/) in Spain.

"Health authority of the Şişli district" could be simply translated as `autoridades` or described with a direct translation:

> Las autoridades sanitarias del distrito de  Şişli

"Head of health authority" could be translated as "**jefe** de las autoridades sanitarias". It could also be translated as "`primer mandatario` de las autoridades sanitarias".

Comment: Thanks a lot! Googling this also results in many results, it seems it is used. I hope one of these two answers can be useful.